# While hovering an id change an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 9 "divs, designed like this:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

what I want to do is when the mouse hovers the number 5 div it will show an image, and when I hover on any other div (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9) it will show a different design on num 5 div.

```html
 <div class="flex-container" id="container">
  <div class="child" id="coop" ></div>
  <div class="child" id="wai"></div>
  <div class="child" id="educ"></div>
  <div class="child" id="tech"> </div>
  <div class="parent" id="index"></div>
  <div class="child" id="pmo"></div>
  <div class="child" id="hobby"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cook"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cont"></div>
 </div>
```

I prefer to work with css because I still lack the experience with js.

Comment: What are you looking for? you want all them have the same behavior on `hover` event ?

Comment: Since you are going to want to show an image you will probably need to put that somewhere in another div and listen to a mouse hover event with javascript. Unless maybe there's a way to workaround in CSS with a background-image property.

Anyways the code you provided doesn't correlate with your question or desired behavior so it's hard to answer.

Comment: as new contributor all of that answers deserved up vote !

Answer (score 3):

```css
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
    
}
.flex-container:hover div:nth-child(5){
  background: yellow;
}
.flex-container div:nth-child(5):hover{
    background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=32);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container" id="container">
  <div class="child" id="coop" ></div>
  <div class="child" id="wai"></div>
  <div class="child" id="educ"></div>
  <div class="child" id="tech"> </div>
  <div class="parent" id="index"></div>
  <div class="child" id="pmo"></div>
  <div class="child" id="hobby"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cook"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cont"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.child',function(e){
   //different design, For example, change the background color
   $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
$(document).on('mouseover','.parent',function(e){
   //show image on tooltip, change image sourc
    $(this).tooltip({ content: '<img 
     src="http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe- 
     brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png" />' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You can change the src of an img with CSS by defining its content URL, like so:

```
#index img {
   content:url("https://i.imgur.com/ZfnIxu8.png");
}
```

To make this on hover, as you might have thought as well, it's simple:

```
#index:hover img {
   content:url("https://i.imgur.com/4XaKXD5.jpg");
}
```

And this solves the first part.

Now, to change other div's with the hover of one div, you simply need to specify :hover on each one of them, and what to do after:

```
#coop:hover #index img, #wait:hover #index img, #educ:hover #index img, 
#tech:hover #index img, #pmo:hover #index img, #hobby:hover #index img, 
#cook:hover #index img, #cont:hover #index img {
   content:url("https://i.imgur.com/6Fb0Dvt.jpg");
}
```

This is saying "whenever I `:hover` on `#id`, apply style defined to `#index img`".

I searched for a cleaner way to write all of that, but unfortunately the `:is` selector is still experimental. [You can read more on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is), but this is what your code would look like:

```
:is(#coop, #wait, #educ, #tech, #pmo, #hobby, #cook, #cont):hover #index img {
   content:url("https://i.imgur.com/lABKzWp.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container div{
background:red;
display:block;
height:10px;
width:100%;
margin:10px;
color:#fff;
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}

#container #index img{
display:none;
}

#container #index:hover img {
display:block;
}

#container .child:hover {

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="flex-container" id="container">
  <div class="child" id="coop" >1</div>
  <div class="child" id="wai">2</div>
  <div class="child" id="educ">3</div>
  <div class="child" id="tech">4 </div>
  <div class="parent" id="index">5
    <img alt="here is the image" src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg"/>
    </div>
  <div class="child" id="pmo"></div>
  <div class="child" id="hobby"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cook"></div>
  <div class="child" id="cont"></div>
 </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```